# Django, How to get template tag rendered data on views.py?

Tags: django

**models.py:**

```
class TestPhoto(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField()
```

**views.py:**

```
def print_test(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.is_ajax():
            testphoto = TestPhoto.objects.all().last()
            # Here is what I'm asking
            print({{ testphoto.file.url }})
            return JsonResponse({'success': 'printed'})
```

How can I get template tag rendered data: `{{ testphoto.file.url }}` on views.py ??

I want to get template tag rendered data in views.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Template`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context) class for this:

```
from django.template import Context, Template

def print_test(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.is_ajax():
            testphoto = TestPhoto.objects.all().last()
            # Here is what I'm asking
            template = Template("{{ testphoto.file.url }}")
            context = Context({"testphoto": testphoto})
            print(template.render(context)) # give you rendered value
            return JsonResponse({'success': 'printed'})
```

**UPD**

But if you just need image's url you can use simple:

```
print(testphoto.file.url)
```